# Where do I find the solidity provisions of Ethereum OPCODEs?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, opcode

There is Solidity Cheat Sheet: https://github.com/manojpramesh/solidity-cheatsheet
There is OPCODEs list: https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes

But is there any list that show opcode's solidity code provisions example;

ADD (Opcode) = + (Solidity Code)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "code provisions" . Solidity is higher language, EVM assembly is the lower level language. `solc` will compile high level code , optimize it if needed, and produce EVM assembly. So this equation `ADD (Opcode) = + (Solidity Code)` doesn't make sense. You want to us to refer you to the solidity sources ???

Comment: I can't really tell what you mean, but you can learn more about Ethereum Virtual Machine Opcodes from: https://www.evm.codes/
and
https://www.ethervm.io/

Answer (score 1):

[Try this link and scroll down a little please.](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.4/assembly.html) I think it is what you have been asked.

| Instruction | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| stop | stop execution, identical to return(0,0) |
| add(x, y) | x + y |
| sub(x, y) | x - y |
| mul(x, y) | x * y |
| div(x, y) | x / y |
| sdiv(x, y) | x / y, for signed numbers in two’s complement |
| mod(x, y) | x % y |
| smod(x, y) | x % y, for signed numbers in two’s complement |
| exp(x, y) | x to the power of y |
| not(x) | ~x, every bit of x is negated |
| lt(x, y) | 1 if x < y, 0 otherwise |
| gt(x, y) | 1 if x > y, 0 otherwise |
| slt(x, y) | 1 if x < y, 0 otherwise, for signed numbers in two’s complement |
| sgt(x, y) | 1 if x > y, 0 otherwise, for signed numbers in two’s complement |
| eq(x, y) | 1 if x == y, 0 otherwise |
| iszero(x) | 1 if x == 0, 0 otherwise |
| and(x, y) | bitwise and of x and y |
| or(x, y) | bitwise or of x and y |
| xor(x, y) | bitwise xor of x and y |
| byte(n, x) | nth byte of x, where the most significant byte is the 0th byte |
| shl(x, y) | logical shift left y by x bits |
| shr(x, y) | logical shift right y by x bits |
| sar(x, y) | arithmetic shift right y by x bits |
| pop(x) | remove the element pushed by x |
| gas | gas still available to execution |
| address | address of the current contract / execution context |
| balance(a) | wei balance at address a |
| caller | call sender (excluding `delegatecall`) |
| call(g, a, v, in, insize, out, outsize) | call contract at address a with input mem[in…(in+insize)) providing g gas and v wei and output area mem[out…(out+outsize)) returning 0 on error (eg. out of gas) and 1 on success |
| callcode(g, a, v, in, insize, out, outsize) | identical to `call` but only use the code from a and stay in the context of the current contract otherwise |
| delegatecall(g, a, in, insize, out, outsize) | identical to `callcode` but also keep `caller` and `callvalue` |
| staticcall(g, a, in, insize, out, outsize) | identical to `call(g, a, 0, in, insize, out, outsize)` but do not allow state modifications |
| return(p, s) | end execution, return data mem[p…(p+s)) |
| revert(p, s) | end execution, revert state changes, return data mem[p…(p+s)) |
| selfdestruct(a) | end execution, destroy current contract and send funds to a |
| origin | transaction sender |
| gasprice | gas price of the transaction |
| blockhash(b) | hash of block nr b - only for last 256 blocks excluding current |
| timestamp | timestamp of the current block in seconds since the epoch |
| gaslimit | block gas limit of the current block |
|  |  |

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what you mean, but you can learn more about Ethereum Virtual Machine Opcodes from:

https://www.evm.codes/
and
https://www.ethervm.io/